# sql query to view the associations

Tags: sql

I attended an interview recently and they gave me the following scenario in SQL:

**Employee table:**

```
Employee{
empId,
name
}
```

**Department Table:**

```
Department{
depId,
depName
}
```

**Employee Department Table:**

```
EmployeeDepartment{
empId
depId
}
```

I was asked to print the result with the following details :

```
EmpID EmpName DepName DepID
```

I could not think of any solution there.

I tried going thru some SO answers but could not understand how they work. Some answers suggest the usage of EXISTS and some use JOINS. But I still can't figure out how this is supposed to work.

Can anyone please tell me how to write the sql query to achieve this with and without the association table ? Specifically without using any JOINS?

Comment: I tried a query with two joins but I don't think that works as expected. I am using sql fiddle which has a similar setup as this question. But it's not working.

Comment: If you cannot do this, why are you interviewing for a SQL job that (presumably) requires SQL abilities?

Comment: If you plan to learn sql, create and fill theese tables with sample values, and try to figure the sql SELECT command with JOIN conditions. One employee can be in multiple departments here.

Comment: Employee>-EmployeeDpartment-<Department.  EmployeeDepartment is an associative table between employee in department to resolve the M:M relationship between employee and department.  thus you would need to join employee to employeedepartment and then department based on the keys which are presumably the fields ending in ID.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's for a full stack developer role. usually we get the queries from the DBA team. We just plug it in and use them in our application. I've never had a chance to do anything with sql rather than just using them in my application. I told the interview that I have only worked on CRUD operation on a single table, not more than that. But he  expected me to answer this.

Comment: @xQbert I have him the solution using two joins (even though I was not clear how it would work). But the interviewer told me that the association table exists to help write the query without using joins .

Comment: @v1shnu By asking this question you've told us you don't know basic SQL. Joins across tables *are basic SQL*. That's kind of the point of a relational database - to relate different pieces of data together. It's okay if you don't know, because we all started out with no knowledge at some point too. But before seeking a job where you might deal with SQL, you really should know the basics.

Comment: @mason I do know about basic sql and I do know about joins. I know how joins work and to join two tables based on a common key. But I just wanted to know how I can get this done WITHOUT USING JOINS because of the association table .

Comment: @v1shnu The "association table" is there to provide a "N to M" relation...

Comment: If the interviewer told you to do it without joins, he was probably trying to confuse you. A join is the standard way to join together data across tables. You can perhaps find a way to do it without joins, but your response to the interviewer could be "I believe this is the cleanest way to accomplish this." Programming is about putting easy to read code together that can be well understood and maintained, not cobbling together ugly and brittle solutions.

Comment: Some SQL implementations, like Oracle DB before 9, does not know the `JOIN` keyword. They use `FROM` with comma delimited tables and `WHERE` with joining conditions, but these are still joins...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I don't think he expected an answer based on db version. But the interviewer spoke as if joins are not even needed when the association table is given.

Comment: Perhaps you simply misunderstood the interviewer.    Write what you know would give you the desired results.  Then if someone says that's not right ask why since you know it works,and if they come back and say it's because you used joins, then say you misunderstood the question and write the query w/o the joins using the in select selects.  I'd defend the joins as being the correct answer as they are by far the most efficient for this question.

Comment: Some consider sub-queries as joins, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    e.EmpID 
    ,e.EmpName
    ,d.DepName 
    ,d.DepID
from EmployeeDepartment ed
inner join Employee e
on ed.EmpID = e.EmpID 
inner join Department d
on ed.DepID=d.DepID
```

I can't see why you would use no joins, The solution below still joins, just in a silly way:

```
select
    ed.EmpID
    ,(select top 1 EmpName from Employee e where e.Empid=ed.Empid) EmpName
    ,ed.DepId
    ,(select top 1 DepName from Department d where d.DepId=ed.DepId) DepName 
from EmployeeDepartment ed
```

Comment: Yes , this is the solution that I came up with somehow, but he wanted one without joins and told me that the association table is there to write the query without joins.

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution. My guess would be that the plan would look the same for the two queries - there are only so many ways to get the info out of the tables. I see no value in avoiding joins - thats kinda what a RDBMS does!

Comment: just to understand, inner join matches key on one table to a key on another and gives the combined result right ? but how does doing another join help adding the other table. Like how does joins help in association between two tables using an intermediate table ? any good resources that explains this better ?

Comment: This addresses the question.  Though the 2nd approach would be slow on large scale tables while the 1st is the long term way to write this.

Comment: @v1shnu I thought you said in the comments on your question that you understood joins. If you have to ask these sorts of questions about joins, then *you don't understand joins*. Which is okay, but don't go misrepresenting yourself as having more knowledge than you do. People won't know what level of explanation is required to teach you.

Comment: @V1shnu.  to get at the data you need in one query you will at times have to join multiple tables.  Imagine the following: a customer, Orderheader, orderItems, items.  Now imagine that someone asked for a list of all items and the quantities sold by customer Name over the past 5 years. At a minimum you would have to join the tables listed above; mixing different types of joins.

Comment: Like others have said, this is really basic Relational Database theory. A table is a relation with unique attributes and relations to other tables.
In this case we have to entities departemt, and employee. Their tables do not relate directly to any other table. ie they have no foreign keys. The EmployeeDepartment  has oly foreign keys, it relates to the department and employee table. This model allows for employees to be inmultiple departments, and for departments to have multiple employees.

Comment: All I wanted to know was how to write the query without using a join and that how to join two tables using an association table as intermediary. Because all I've tried is joining two table using a common key on the two tables. But everyone here just wants to give their suggestion on searching for jobs, applying for the right position and asking me not to think big of myself (which I am really not). If someone had given this time to just explain a little better, this question would have helped many beginners like me. Thanks @SørenKongstad for the answer.

Comment: The second query is a correlated subquery. It essentially is still  a join due to the where  d.DepId=ed.DepId clause which creates an implicit join. However, it does this row by row so it is much much slower than a regular join. If you are interviewing at a place that wants to avoid joins, they are incompetent at best and there codebase of SQL will be a nightmare to work with.

Comment: I think it might be just for the interview because he was somewhat okayish with my join solution. I think I will have to learn how joins work on more than two tables as @xQbert has stated. I could not find any resource online that explains this the joining of more than two tables.

Comment: I've not run into a limit on # of tables joined (though I know there is one) and I often do 10+ to get the results desired.  I know of many people who say they didn't know you could join more than 3 tables together; thus my prior comment.  Joins on PK/FK relationships are fast efficient and provide desired results.

Comment: Even I did not know joins can happen over multiple tables until now. I only thought it was only between two tables. That is why I was wondering how the interviewer accepted my two joins solution even though I did not know how it worked. I'm actually trying multiple joins in sql fiddle. Can you help me out with that ?

Comment: @xQbert i'm testing multiple table joins here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where_and where I'm trying to join Products, Suppliers and Categories. Joining two tables work. But joining three does not . This is my query so far - SELECT p.productid , p.productname ,s.suppliername, c.categoryname  FROM Products p inner join suppliers s on p.supplierid = s.supplierid inner join categories c on c.categoryid = p.categoryid; It throws an syntax exception.

Comment: what you have posted runs fine for me on that link.  77 records returned.  however this is no longer relevant to the question at hand so this is my last comment. `SELECT p.productid , p.productname ,s.suppliername, c.categoryname, O.CustomerID
FROM Products p 
inner join suppliers s 
  on p.supplierid = s.supplierid 
inner join categories c 
  on c.categoryid = p.categoryid
INNER JOIN orderdetails od
 on od.productID = P.ProductId
INNER JOIN ORDERS O  
 on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID` works fine too. for 518 records.